# Is the tag [logical-consistency] workable?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

I made the tag [logical-consistency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-consistency) the other day, and set its description to be

> For questions about the stability of a concept inside a specific context

The goal for this was to make a tag that would indicate a self-consistent answer was desired. The idea was also to promote logically thought out answers without being as rigorous as [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) was, and that the concept answered with could include handwavium and unobtainium answers, as long as they didn't break the universe.

On thinking on it the day after, I wonder if this is actually an appropriate tag; if this concept is part of the base assumption of answers here on Worldbuilding, so that's the main question; should it remain?

Also, if it fits, is there a better "description text" for it?

Answer (score 10):

I feel like [logical-consistency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-consistency) is a duplicate of [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check). The latter is designed to do what your tag does: ask if an idea is consistent within the laws of physics of the universe in question. You can use [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) on a question whose premise involves the force of gravity falling off as $e^{-|r|}$, rather than $r^{-2}$, whereas it would be harder to justify using [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based); while we could answer the question mathematically (likely), we couldn't use the physics of our universe to answer it. But we *could* use the physics of the question's universe; [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) covers just that.

For the record, the tag wiki excerpt for [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) is

> For questions asking whether or not a particular concept is realistic in a given context. Answers to these questions should provide a yes or no answer with supporting information. Consider alternatively the science-based and hard-science tags. This tag should never be the only tag on a question, it frames how a question should be answered, not the topic.

I think the third sentence could use some clarification along the lines I gave earlier, but most of it fits what I said. An important point to consider is the last sentence. [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check), along with [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) and [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science), is what's known as a meta tag. It doesn't tell us anything about the content itself, just what kind of answers are expected.

Meta tags [are generally not encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), although there are exceptions. Some science sites, for instance, use [homework](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) or some variant thereof (though others have killed that with a vengeance!). The consensus on Worldbuilding seems to be that these three meta tags are okay, as far as I know.

So, I guess my main point is that I think [logical-consistency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-consistency) should be listed as a synonym of [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check). I think the sentiment behind the tag is indeed appropriate, but it's redundant. If it ends up staying as its own tag, though, I'd recommend looking closely at the [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) tag wiki excerpt and tag wiki, and being careful to distinguish between the two (if such distinctions exist). Mentioning that [logical-consistency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-consistency) is a meta tag would also be good.

---

As per the voting on this answer, I've added [logical-consistency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-consistency) as a synonym of [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check).

Comment: I agree, logical-consistency is a duplicate of reality-check :)

Comment: Not that a double mod consensus needs it, but I concur.